# How to run call a sharedlibrary pipeline inside another pipline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I've written a pipeline as a shared library and I would like to call as one of the stage of master pipeline, but I am getting an error that probably node is not defined. What is the best approach for that? In second case I rewrite sharedTest as a standard pipe line and use "build job" instead of call a shared library, but in that I am repeating a code in some places.
So generally I would like to have:
sharedTest as a independed pipeline but also reusing it in some places, so first one is simple because I can create a separate pipeline where I am importing lib and then calling such lib method. The problem is when I would like to use a shared pipeline as a stage of master piple.

sharedTest.groovy :

```
def call() {
    pipeline{
        agent {
            label "ansirobotSpy3-devel"
        }
        parameters {
            choice(name: 'TEST', choices: ['bts1', 'bts2'], description: '')
            string(name: 'PATH', defaultValue: '/bts1/, description: '')
        }
        environment {
            HTTPS_PROXY = 'http://1.1.1.1'
            HTTP_PROXY = 'http://1.1.1.1'
        }
        stages{
            stage('Test stage'){
                steps{
                    script {
                        sh "ls -lart ./*"
                        installPyLibs('pytest')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

master pipeline:

```
...
 stage("tests"){
                    agent none
                    options {
                        skipDefaultCheckout()
                    }
                    when{
                        beforeAgent true
                        allOf{
                            not { expression { currentBuild.result == 'ABORTED' } }
                            not { expression { SharedTest == 'true' } }
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        script {
                            stage ("Seek && Destoy") {       
                               sharedTest()
                   
                            }
                            stage ("Deploy") {                            
                                def deploy = build job: 'Deploy',
                                    parameters: [
                                        string(name: 'BUILD_NUMBER', value: "${env.NEW_BUILD_NR_VAR}")
                                    ], wait: true, propagate: false
                            }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience Jenkins doesn't allow using shared libraries locally. I did a workaround registering my shared library this way:

```
library identifier: 'LIBRARYNAME@BRANCH',
        retriever: modernSCM([$class: 'GitSCMSource',
                              credentialsId: 'CREDENTIALS_FROM_JENKINS',
                              id: 'GUID',
                              remote: 'CLONE_LINK_TO_GIT_REPO',
                              traits: [[$class: 'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait']]])
```

This also can be achieved using UI and registering the library. More on that here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

As for the code - I assume your pipeline is inside `vars` folder in your repository.  (details about this here: [folder structure](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#directory-structure)) .This way they will be accessible during the pipeline.

Let's assume I have file `vars/internalStepTestEcho.groovy`. After loading a library this can be accessed using:

```
internalStepTestEcho()
```